# How to get out of a migration failure without reverting to backups

Tags: gitlab

So what are my options if an update to the next major version fails due to database migrations not working? (Parts of the migrations already seem in place?

The problem is that backups all contain that column and I'm not even sure when this problem started. I have done a few backup recoveries a couple of months ago all seemed well at the time, but now I'm pretty sure something went wrong there.

I can think of;
1 going in manually into postgres to delete columns. And try to update then. (how?). Might be that there are other migrations problems further down the line.
2 exporting individual projects, reset to factory settings and reimport all projects. This would depend on the export format (if it's a sql dump I would end up in the same situation)
3 hoping an expert read this and helps me out :-)

Because this ticket hasn't gained any attention https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3156 I'm now trying my luck here. For now it seems I'm stuck at gitlab/gitlab-ce:10.3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had to address this problem (Thankfully!) but in the GitLab docs, they do have a section in their Updating GitLab area about recovering from a failed or partial upgrade. (They seem to indicate that this may happen after you restore from back-up, so that matches with your statement that you have done several backup recoveries).

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/restore_after_failure.html

They say you may have to go through this several times (for different migration steps) before you get yourself back to a point where the migration you want rolls forward successfully.

Based on the log you posted in their issue tracker, I see it failed on migration 20171106171453, so your command to get over the first hurdle probably looks like this (Note different commands depending on Source or Omnibus install):

**(Source Install)**
`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:db:mark_migration_complete[20171106171453] RAILS_ENV=production`

**(Omnibus Install)**
`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:db:mark_migration_complete[20171106171453]`

Again, I have never done this before, so I would take a fresh back-up before trying (because that has worked so well in the prior instances, right?!), and read their doc and warnings thoroughly before attempting.

Good Luck!

Comment: bit difficult to do in a dockerized environment but it did work. Only the mentioned migration needed to be marked as completed. Thanks again